# Print option for the contents of a jqueryui dialog popup? is this possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When someone clicks a button, it opens up a jquery-ui popup window  (dialog).

I need to add 'print' button on this popup, so someone can print out the contents of the popup dialog.

is this possible? how can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few plugins for this, [like jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) ([demo here](http://www.recoding.it/wp-content/uploads/demos/jqprint-demo.htm)), you can just add a print button that calls that functionality, for example:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  buttons: { 
    "Print": function() { $("#dialog").jqprint(); },
    "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
  }
});
```

Comment: demo seems to go no where

Comment: I used this [printArea plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/PrintArea/) instead. Worked great once I set the dialog to `modal=false`.